# видео в картинке

Tags: html, css, css3

как сделать картинку внутри картинки монитор

```
           <div class="video">
                <div class="box-video">
                    <img src="img/video.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
```

как здесь

[image: css3]

Comment: Вставь код так, чтобы запустить можно было полноценно.Завтра, помогу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер видео в этом случае будет 500x330 жёлтый контейнер это и есть видео но сюда я его не добавил

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 140px);
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: 0.24s;
}

.image-container1:hover {
  transform: translate(-50%, 140px)scale(1.1);
}

.image-container2 {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.video-container {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: 500px;
  height: 330px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video-container"><video id="video" src="video/item.mp4" width="500" height="330"></video></div>
  <div class="image-container1"><img id="play" src=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVtOm.png" alt="play" title="play"></div>
  <div class="image-container2"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Udu.png" alt="laptop"></div>
</div>
```